# UICollectionView does not stay selected after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I select a cell, it turns blue, which is good. Then when I scroll up and the cell out of view, it turns back to original color. Not sure how to fix this.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection=YES;

    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *datasetCell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];  
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *datasetCell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your first method, you are practically telling the collection view to select any cell that it asks for. Instead, you should check whether the cell you return has the same path as the selected one, and only then give it color:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.selectedIndexPath]) // you need to create selectedIndexPath as a property
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

And then:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

Comment: I think this has helped. I have to be able to select more than one cell but I can add them to an array and then check if they are selected. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Like you said indeed, for multiple element selection, you could add/remove elements from your array as they are selected/deselected. Please make sure you accept/upvote the answer if you think it has helped you.

Comment: I have a new follow-up question posted today about the icons in the cells.

Answer (score 2):

When cell are  reused, the selection state is lost. So you need to save the indexPath of the selection in didSelectItemAtIndexPath. And when you dequeue the cell you need to check and restore the state